# Api using subdomain instead of the full website url

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hopefully someone can help with my question.

I have an api running under asp.net core 3 and it is access for example as https://SOMEDOMAINNAME/api/myapifunction

Is it possible under IIS or via a setting in the project startup.cs to be able to access using the url of:-

https://api.SOMEDOMAINNAME/myapifunction

Thanks in advance

Dr

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use IIS url rewrite feature to help you achieve this requirement.

It will rewrite the url from `https://api.SOMEDOMAINNAME/myapifunction` to `https://SOMEDOMAINNAME/api/myapifunction`.

More details about how to install it, you could refer to this [article](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

After installed it, you could add below config setting into your web.config file.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteRule">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^api.SOMEDOMAINNAME" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://SOMEDOMAINNAME/api/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, what you need to do is deploy your Web API under a subdomain in IIS, instead of using the TL domain as the base URL.

Once you do that in IIS, make this changes to your API controller:

**Instead of**

```
      [Route("api/[controller]"), ApiController]
      public class ControllerName : ControllerBase
      {

      }
```

which gives you
https://SOMEDOMAINNAME/api/myapifunction

**You do this Instead**

```
  [Route("[controller]"), ApiController]
  public class ControllerName : ControllerBase
  {

  }
```

and you have this https://api.SOMEDOMAINNAME/myapifunction